# python specify weights for linear regression

Tags: python, statistics, regression, linear-regression, summary

I have a few linear regression models and due to underlying reasons need to need have the weights for a set regression to be user-defined. is it possible to get an OLS summary based user-defined weights rather than the linear regression weights it finds itself?

Comment: I think I asked the same question and just got the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52015778/can-we-set-fix-the-coefficients-in-a-regression-equation-in-python

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a linear regression, and you know some of the weights, you can essentially mathematically reduce it to a simpler regression. For instance assume you have the following regression

z = ax + by

Given z, x, y it's relatively easy to set up a linear regression. If you want the user to specify (a) rather than having the system solve for it, then your expression becomes

z' = by where z' = z - ax, where a is a coefficient that is specified by your end user.

model = sm.OLS(Predicted_Z, Actual_Z)
results = model.fit()
print(results.summary())

Comment: I understand this bit what I want is A specified and a nice print out of the statistical summary like OLS provides when you run it

Comment: Just do the regular OLS summary for your predicted Z vs. actual Z'

model = sm.OLS(Actual_Z, Predicted_Z)
results = model.fit()
print(results.summary())

Comment: sorry i am not making this clear I have all the weights so there is no need to run the actual regression as such; I just want the fit statistics based on my defined weights (they may not be optimal weights) but that doesnt matter for this use case