# Can we set / fix the coefficients in a regression equation in Python

Tags: python, regression

I've been trying to find a way of specifying pre-defined coefficients in a OLS/GLS regression in Python. I can do this in R using `offset`, but there doesn't seem to be anything similar in Python.

R equivalent:

```
model=lm(y~x+offset(0.2*z))
```

So in this example x and z are our independent variables, and x is predicted by the model but we have specified the impact of z is 0.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) you *can* perform regression analysis in Python with a [style similar to R](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/example_formulas.html). There you will find `offset` as an argument in *some* of the regression functions. One example is [GLM](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/glm.html).

With a dataset such as this:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 3), columns=list('yxz'))
df

#           y         x         z
# 0  0.091761 -1.987569 -0.219672
# 1  0.357113  1.477894 -0.518270
# 2 -0.808494 -0.501757  0.915402
# 3  0.328751 -0.529760  0.513267
# 4  0.097078  0.968645 -0.702053
# 5 -0.327662 -0.392108 -1.463515
# 6  0.296120  0.261055  0.005113
# 7 -0.234587 -1.415371 -0.420645
```

You can do it like this:

```
known = 0.2

res1 = smf.glm('y ~ x', data = df, offset=known*df['z']).fit()
print(res1.summary())

# ==============================================================================
# Dep. Variable:                      y   No. Observations:                    8
# Model:                            GLM   Df Residuals:                        6
# .
# .
# ==============================================================================
#                  coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Intercept      0.0614      0.165      0.373      0.709      -0.261       0.384
# x              0.1478      0.148      0.995      0.320      -0.143       0.439
# ==============================================================================
```

You could also run a sanity check  by doing the same thing manually. You can create an offset like this:

```
offset = known*df['z']
y_offset = df['y']-offset
df2  = pd.concat([pd.Series(y_diff), df['x']], axis = 1)
df2.columns = ['y_diff', 'x']

res2 = smf.glm('y_offset ~ x', data = df2).fit()
print(res2.summary())

# ==============================================================================
# Dep. Variable:               y_offset   No. Observations:                    8
# Model:                            GLM   Df Residuals:                        6
# .
# .
# ==============================================================================
#                  coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Intercept      0.0614      0.165      0.373      0.709      -0.261       0.384
# x              0.1478      0.148      0.995      0.320      -0.143       0.439
# ==============================================================================
```

Comment: No problem! Would you consider marking my suggestion as the accepted answer? Others that have taken the time to answer other questions of yours would appreciate that as well. The most important consequence of this is that it makes it MUCH easier to decide which challenges we should try to solve. All accepted answers are highlighted by green. Also, now that you have earned more than 15 reputation points, you have the ability to upvote answers that are useful to you.