# Can i specify my own parameters in statsmodels?

Tags: parameters, regression, statsmodels

Granted a model is just an equation and can just be typed in but is there a way where you can specify your own parameters for a specific type of mode. say you want to create a logistic model with beta0 = -13, beta1 = 12 and so on. is there a function that allows you to do that??

Comment: What's the purpose? The main model results like standard errors and inference will not be valid if parameters have not been estimated by maximum likelihood.

Comment: [Can we set / fix the coefficients in a regression equation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52015778/9987623)

Comment: There is nothing Poisson in your question, removed that tag. Don't use tags that have nothing to do with the nature of your problem.

Comment: @pjs you misunderstood my question. The word poisson may not have been explicitly stated but the concept applies to pretty much all data fitting. I don't see where your coming from.

Comment: @hghebrem Please read the help section of the site. Tags should be directly relevant to the question being asked. You are spamming when you add tags that have no bearing on your question. If a concept applies in general, you don't need to and shouldn't tag one particular case. Your question doesn't mention binomial, geometric, Gaussian, gamma, uniform, etc., etc., etc. distributions either, so do you think it would make sense to add all of those as well? If not, then you have singled out the Poisson as somehow unique, but not explained why.