# Fix a regression coefficient in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics, regression

I'm doing some regressions using Numpy [Polynomial.fit](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html#numpy.polyfit) but I would like to fix some of the coefficients, for example the zero order coefficient.

Is there a way to do so using standard Python libraries?
In the documentation it seems that there is no option to do so, and here on SO I only found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52015778/can-we-set-fix-the-coefficients-in-a-regression-equation-in-python) suggesting to use the statsmodels library, which I rather not use.

Here is the code I'm using now, but I don't think it will be of help:

```
x = df['Time'] 
y = df['Velocity']
lin_reg = np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(x, y, 1)
m = lin_reg.coef[1]
q = lin_reg.coef[0]
```

I would like to fix the value for q at, let's say, 2.24.

Comment: Can you provide more detail:
- example data and function
- example of not working code but showing your intent

Comment: I wrote my code, but I'm not asking to fix the code, just some tips for methods/functions

Comment: If you have an explicit form in mind, it might be best to adapt a least squares for the job. Numpy presents a solution (see link below)  for y= mx+q. For your purpose you would want to substract q from y, and then fit y-q against m_1*x+m_2*x**2+m_3*x**3+m_4*x**4 ... . The higher powers can simply be added as extra columns. So contrary to what you might think least squares can handle non-linear relations. 
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq